# Android Mobile App feature that compare two location

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, location, maps

I am newly and currently learning about kotlin and android programming
I want to make an app that compares and detect which one between two things that closer to me, and the compared thing is,
for example, two different McDonald franchise based on a google map location,
I have no idea how am I supposed to build this, can u guys help me to identify what kind of technology that is suitable for my school project?
thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would recommend taking a look at [ask] for some tips on how to ask a good question! Unfortunately this isn't a tutorial site, you need to have a specific question that can be definitively answered by the volunteers here, this question is very broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the location of two points and use this method to compare the distance between each point with your current location

then choose the smaller one

```
    private fun calculationByDistance(location: Location, EndP: Location): Double {
        val Radius = 6371 // radius of earth in Km
        val lat1 = location.latitude
        val lat2: Double = EndP.latitude
        val lon1 = location.longitude
        val lon2: Double = EndP.longitude
        val dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1)
        val dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1)
        val a = (Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                + (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
                * Math.sin(dLon / 2)))
        val c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a))
        val valueResult = Radius * c
        val km = valueResult / 1
        val newFormat = DecimalFormat("####")
        val kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km))
        val meter = valueResult % 1000
        val meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter))
        Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
                + " Meter   " + meterInDec)
        return Radius * c
    }
```

you can get your current location by following this documentation
[her](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current)